# set stdout as a default output file and set deafult value to 3 in bash

Tags: bash, docker

I am trying to use flags to set an output file for my bash program. I would like to make it possible in case I havent expliticly entered arguments to use stdout. Additionally, I set number of iterations. In case I do not provide this flag, I would like to set it to 3.

This is what I have:

```sh
while getopts i:o: option
do
case "${option}"
in
i) ITERATIONS=${OPTARG};;
o) OUTPUTF=${OPTARG};;
esac
done

docker-compose up -d
for i in {1..ITERATIONS}
    do docker-compose run specs | tee OUTPUTF
    sleep 1
done
docker-compose stop
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default values are easy; just assign them before the `while` loop. If the loop never overrides the value, they'll keep the default values.

The tricky part is figuring out a proper default for `OUTPUTF`. You can use `/dev/stdout` if your file system exposes, or maybe `/dev/fd/0`, but there isn't really a standard name you can use.

As an alternative, I'd recommend piping the output of `docker-compose` to a function whose definition can depend on the use of the `-o` option.

```
iterations=3
log_output () { cat; }  # Meant to ignore its argument
outputf=                # default value doesn't really matter

while getopts i:o: option; do
  case $option in
    i) iterations=$OPTARG ;;
    o) log_output () { tee "$1"; } 
       outputf=$OPTARG 
       ;;
  esac
done

docker-compose up -d
for ((i=0; i < $iterations; i++)); do  # Can't use parameters in a brace expression
    docker-compose run specs
    sleep 1
done | log_output "$outputf"
docker-compose stop
```

By default, `log_output` simply passes its input to `cat`, ignoring its argument. If you use `-o`, the `log_output` is redefined as a wrapper around `tee` and saves the output file name. Either way, `log_output` is called with `"$outputf"` as its argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your iterations to have a default value, you can just set it to a default before the case statement with something like `declare -i ITERATIONS=3;`.

If I understand the first part of your question correctly, you to optionally also write the output to a file if one is provided to the bash scrip, right? If so, there are lots of ways to do this, but I think a simple solution would be to have `OUTPUTF` default to `/dev/null` and overwrite this output path if one is provided.

This results in the following:

```
declare -i ITERATIONS=3;
declare OUTPUTF=/dev/null;

while getopts i:o: option; do
    case "${option}" in
    i) ITERATIONS="${OPTARG}";;
    o) OUTPUTF="${OPTARG}";;
    esac
done

docker-compose up -d
for i in {1..ITERATIONS}; do
    docker-compose run specs
    sleep 1
done | tee "$OUTPUTF"
docker-compose stop
```

It is worth noting that I moved `tee` to the outside of the for loop because otherwise a new process will be spawned and the output file will be overwritten every iteration.